# How do I use no-ip in broaband connection from service provider?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, dynamic-dns

My computer is connected to a broadband line and I have no access to the admin page. The providers use same ip for all its users, and internal ip is dynamic. So I cannot use the admin page to portforward. Will no-ip dns work like a vpn then because I can use vpns?

Comment: It's a long time since I had cable, but I don't think it worked as you describe, but maybe this is a way to squeeze more life out of IPv4. You are not going to get port forwarding, as this would to be to the exclusion of all the others on the same subnet. I think you will need to pay for a fixed IP from your ISP or an external supplier and they will supply what you need to route traffic to your server, though I speak as someone who has not had to do this. An alternative is to sync your web-site with an external host (there are free ones), or maybe you can get what you want from remote access.

Comment: _''sync your web-site with an external host''_ . Can you please explain this process it will help very much.

Comment: What I was thinking of was something like Google Drive, where you set up a local directory which is automatically kept in step with an on-line directory, so that any local changes are copied to the on-line drive and vice versa. (There are other providers who provide a similar service: I use one from my ISP.) Alternatively, you can make all the files you want to access remotely available by including them in a web-site locally which you mirror on a remote server, but keeping the two in step is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

All No-IP DNS will do will associate your internet facing IP with a DNS record.

You really would need to talk to your network administrator about setting up a port forwarding rule for you.